# removing / adding markers leaves artifacts

Tags: google-maps-api-3, javafx-webengine

when I clear all markers and then re-add them, I end up with artifacts.  The image below shows the artifacts.  the 5 buttons add one marker and then up to 5 more markers.  they clear all the markers before adding new ones.  clicking on the buttons 5,4,3,2,1 leaves the image below.  zooming out and back in draws the markers correctly

[image]

swing app using jfxpanel:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import netscape.javascript.JSObject;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FrmMap2 extends JFrame {
    private final JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    private WebEngine engine;
    private FrmMap2 me = null;

    protected String sBounds;

    public FrmMap2() {
        me = this;
        jbInit();
    }


    protected void jbInit() {
        createScene();

        JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
        pnl.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        pnl.add(jfxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton btn = new JButton("Clear");
        btn.addActionListener(evt -> onClear(0));

        JPanel pnl2 = new JPanel();
        pnl2.add(btn);

        for (int x=1; x<6;x++) {
            JButton btn1 = new JButton(""+x);
            final int y = x;
            btn1.addActionListener(evt -> onClear(y));
            pnl2.add(btn1);
        }

        pnl.add(pnl2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1400, 1000));
        getContentPane().add(pnl);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    protected void onClear(int level) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> { engine.executeScript("clearMarkers()"); });
        if (level > 0)
            onAddMarkers(level);
    }
    protected void onAddMarkers(int level) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> { engine.executeScript("addMarker(33.90748,-117.187289,'Test Location 1','white','Test Location 1',-1)"); });
        if (level > 0)  
            Platform.runLater(() -> { engine.executeScript("addMarker(33.9134997,-117.1915758,'Test Location 2','green','Test Location 2',957)"); });
        if (level > 1)  
            Platform.runLater(() -> { engine.executeScript("addMarker(33.9123479,-117.1915805,'Test Location 3','green','Test Location 3',958)"); });
        if (level > 2)  
            Platform.runLater(() -> { engine.executeScript("addMarker(33.913082,-117.1915775,'Test Location 4','green','Test Location 4',959)"); });
        if (level > 3)  
            Platform.runLater(() -> { engine.executeScript("addMarker(33.912805,-117.192108,'Test Location 5','green','Test Location 5',960)"); });
        if (level > 4)  
            Platform.runLater(() -> { engine.executeScript("addMarker(33.9177624,-117.203623,'Test Location 6','green','Test Location 6',1335)"); });
    }
    protected void createScene() {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                WebView view = new WebView();
                engine = view.getEngine();
                URL urlGoogleMaps = null;
                try {
                    urlGoogleMaps = Paths.get("mapview3.html").toUri().toURL();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }
                engine.load(urlGoogleMaps.toExternalForm());

                JSObject window = (JSObject) engine.executeScript("window");
                window.setMember("app", me);
                jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(view));
            }
        });     
    }

    public void logit(String str) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FrmMap2 map = new FrmMap2();
        map.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

html:
    
    
    
    
    
    Map
    
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

```
#map {
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onLoad="initMap()">
    <div id="map">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=AIzaSyCcdMK5ngbSNxXno9ZRlOivVHvLoX6XyH0&libraries=places"></script>
    <script>
        var map;
        var markers = [];
        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center : {
                    lat : 33.90748,
                    lng : -117.187289
                },
                zoom : 15
            });
        }

        // Removes the markers from the map, but keeps them in the array.
        function clearMarkers2() {
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                markers[i].setMap(null);
            }
        }

        function clearMarkers1() {
            markers.forEach(function(marker) {
                marker.setMap(null);
            });
        }

        function clearMarkers() {
            clearMarkers1();
            //clearMarkers2();
            markers = [];
            app.logit("MARKERS CLEARED");
        }
        function addMarker(lat, long, name, color, popover, id) {
            app.logit("ADDING MARKER: " + lat + "," + long + "," + name + "," + color + "," + id);
            var marker = createMarker("", name, new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long), popover, id);
            markers.push(marker);
        }
        function createMarker(iconname, placename, location, popover, mid) {

            // Create a marker for each place.
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map : map,
                title : placename,
                position : location
            });
            var infobulle = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content : popover
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
                infobulle.open(map, marker);
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
                infobulle.close();
            });
            return marker;
        }
    </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not the best way to solve this question, but I was able to remove the artifacts by creating a pseudo redraw function and calling it after clearing all the markers and after adding all the new ones.

```
function redraw() {
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1);
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1);
}
```